# Invalid block tag: 'keywords_for_order', expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

sorry I'm at my wit's end here. I have this code working locally but for some reason on the server when I try and run this tag I get an error and I have no idea why. Here's the template code:

```
{% load blog_tags keyword_tags i18n future %}

{% block blog_keywords %}
{% keywords_for_order blog.blogpost as tags %}
{% if tags %}
<h3>{% trans "Tags" %}</h3>
<ul class="unstyled tags">
{% for tag in tags %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url "blog_post_list_tag" tag.slug %}"
        class="tag-weight-1">{{ tag }}</a>
    ({{ tag.item_count }})
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the keyword_tags.py file:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models import Model, Count

from mezzanine import template
from mezzanine.conf import settings
from mezzanine.generic.fields import KeywordsField
from mezzanine.generic.models import AssignedKeyword, Keyword


register = template.Library()

@register.as_tag
def keywords_for(*args):
    """
    Return a list of ``Keyword`` objects for the given model instance
    or a model class. In the case of a model class, retrieve all
    keywords for all instances of the model and apply a ``weight``
    attribute that can be used to create a tag cloud.
    """

    # Handle a model instance.
    if isinstance(args[0], Model):
        obj = args[0]
        if hasattr(obj, "get_content_model"):
            obj = obj.get_content_model() or obj
        # There can only be one ``KeywordsField``, find it.
        for field in obj._meta.many_to_many:
            if isinstance(field, KeywordsField):
                break
        else:
            return []
        keywords_manager = getattr(obj, field.name)
        return [a.keyword for a in keywords_manager.select_related("keyword")]

    # Handle a model class.
    try:
        app_label, model = args[0].split(".", 1)
    except ValueError:
        return []

    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)
    assigned = AssignedKeyword.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
    keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(assignments__in=assigned)
    keywords = keywords.annotate(item_count=Count("assignments"))
    if not keywords:
        return []
    settings.use_editable()
    counts = [keyword.item_count for keyword in keywords]
    min_count, max_count = min(counts), max(counts)
    sizes = settings.TAG_CLOUD_SIZES
    step = (max_count - min_count) / (sizes - 1)
    if step == 0:
        steps = [sizes / 2]
    else:
        steps = range(min_count, max_count, step)[:sizes]
    for keyword in keywords:
        c = keyword.item_count
        diff = min([(abs(s - c), (s - c)) for s in steps])[1]
        keyword.weight = steps.index(c + diff) + 1
    return keywords



@register.as_tag
def keywords_for_order(*args):


    # Handle a model instance.
    if isinstance(args[0], Model):
        obj = args[0]
        if hasattr(obj, "get_content_model"):
            obj = obj.get_content_model() or obj
        # There can only be one ``KeywordsField``, find it.
        for field in obj._meta.many_to_many:
            if isinstance(field, KeywordsField):
                break
        else:
            return []
        keywords_manager = getattr(obj, field.name)
        return [a.keyword for a in keywords_manager.select_related("keyword")]

    # Handle a model class.
    try:
        app_label, model = args[0].split(".", 1)
    except ValueError:
        return []

    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)
    assigned = AssignedKeyword.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
    keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(assignments__in=assigned)
    keywords = keywords.annotate(item_count=Count("assignments")).order_by('-item_count')[:2]
    if not keywords:
        return []

    return keywords
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/USERNAME/webapps/lion_dev/lion/roar/templates/blog/includes/tagcloud_panel.html, error at line 4
Invalid block tag: 'keywords_for_order', expected 'endblock'

1   {% load blog_tags keyword_tags i18n future %}
2   
3   {% block blog_keywords %}
4   {% keywords_for_order blog.blogpost as tags %}
5   {% if tags %}
6   <h3>{% trans "Tags" %}</h3>
7   <ul class="unstyled tags">
8   {% for tag in tags %}
9   <li>
10      <a href="{% url "blog_post_list_tag" tag.slug %}"
11          class="tag-weight-1">{{ tag }}</a>
12      ({{ tag.item_count }})
13  </li>
14  {% endfor %}
```

So yeah, I have no clue why this template tags file isn't being seen. It's got an **init**.py file in it too so it's not that. Best, and thanks for any help,

Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you editing the keyword_tags.py file in Mezzanine directly?

You shouldn't be - so if you've done the right thing and copied it into your project or app somehow, chances are the Mezzanine version is getting loaded, and not your version. Try giving it a different name so that they don't collide.

Comment: Hey Stephen, yeah I'm not editing it directly, the idea was to override the mezzanine version kind of like how you're supposed to do with template customization, but I'll try it again. I was getting the same error when I imported a different file though.